# Kaspersky 10 blocking my exchange server emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, anti-virus, exchange, kaspersky

i'm a system administrator for about 400 client machines and i need help please. I have recently installed Kaspersky 10 on my domain and now the individual users can't access their exchange emails. if i disable the the antivirus the email flow through without any problems but as soon as i activate it the emails are blocked again. Has someone else ever encountered this problem??? i'm trying to figure out what's causing the anomaly in the behaviour of the endpoint solution since it was performing reasonably well previously. Kindly assist me please

Answer (score 1):

> Kaspersky

Found your problem.
Remove this utter piece of crap and everything will work flawlessly.

Edit: Just for clarification. This is not a trollpost. Kaspersky is probably the worst software I've ever seen. It blocks everything, slows down your machine and regularly complete kills the computer it's running on.

Uninstall it (or better: reinstall all machines you've installed it on) and get some other antivirus-software.

And another edit: If you insist on using Kaspersky: Do you have the mail gateway feature?